# Change position of UIView doesn't work

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiview, ios7

I have a UIView and I would like to move it up by 50.

I wrote the following:

```
NSLog(@"before %@",NSStringFromCGRect(_flixSuggestionsView.frame));
_flixSuggestionsView.frame = CGRectMake(_flixSuggestionsView.frame.origin.x, _flixSuggestionsView.frame.origin.y-45, _flixSuggestionsView.frame.size.width, _flixSuggestionsView.frame.size.height);    
NSLog(@"after %@",NSStringFromCGRect(_flixSuggestionsView.frame));
```

The output is:

```
 before {{0, 175}, {320, 324}}
 after {{0, 130}, {320, 324}}
```

But the UIView stays in the same location.

What am I missing?

Comment: Check that Autolayout (or any autosizing options) is not active.

Comment: it is active. but don't I need it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If any Autolayout constraints are defined for the view, these determine the view's
position (relative to other UI elements). If you want to control the position "manually",
you have to remove all constraints regarding this view, or switch off Autolayout completely
for the view controller.